# How to remove junglediskserver

Tags: dpkg, jungledisk

I need to remove `junglediscserver` from my server.  I installed it using the .deb file they provide and not apt-get so I'm not sure how to remove it.

I tried `apt-get junglediskserver remove` as `root` and it says directories are not empty so they weren't removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dpkg -r packagename`.